# Scrapy LinkExtractor fails to find existing url

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a Crawler like this:

```
class SkySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "spider_v1"
    allowed_domains = [
        "atsu.edu",
    ]

    start_urls = [
        "http://www.atsu.edu",
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(
            INFO_LINKS_EXTRACTOR,
            follow=True,
            callback='parse_item',
          ),
     )
    def parse_item(self, response):
        print("ENTERED!")
        item = SportsScraperItem()
        item["contact"] = self._parse_contact(response)
        return item
```

In my **helpers.py** I have:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


def _r(string):
    return f"(.*?)(\b{string}\b)(.*)"


INFO_LINKS_EXTRACTOR = LinkExtractor(
    allow=(
        _r('about'),
    ),
    unique=True,
)
```

I know that *atsu.edu* has a link **https://www.atsu.edu/about-atsu/**, but my extractor seems like does not see it and `parse_item()` method is not run. What am I doing wrong here?
**EDIT 1**:
*Logs*:

```
2019-10-01 15:40:58 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-10-01 15:40:58 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-10-01 15:40:58 [steppersspider_v1] INFO: Spider opened: steppersspider_v1
2019-10-01 15:40:58 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-10-01 15:40:59 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.atsu.edu/robots.txt> from <GET http://WWW.ATSU.EDU/robots.txt>
2019-10-01 15:41:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.atsu.edu/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-10-01 15:41:11 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.atsu.edu/> from <GET http://WWW.ATSU.EDU>
2019-10-01 15:41:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.atsu.edu/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-10-01 15:41:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.atsu.edu/> (referer: None)
2019-10-01 15:41:19 [steppersspider_v1] DEBUG: Saved file steppers-www.atsu.edu.html
2019-10-01 15:41:20 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-10-01 15:41:20 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

**EDIT 2**
[Here](https://regex101.com/r/WeeFqK/1) is how I tested this regexp on regexp101.com.

**EDIT 3**
Working function for regexp:

```
def _r(string):
    return r"^(.*?)(\b{string}\b)(.*)$".format(string=string)
```

Comment: what site are you scraping? maybe that site loads that data on AJAX

Comment: @Umair its atsu.edu - I see this link in source html, so its not fetched by AJAX

Comment: post your logs here, does scraper goes to that ABOUT url?

Comment: Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and rewrite your question accordingly, including the target URL that you mention in a comment.

Comment: @Umair - posted logs

Comment: @Chiefir looks like the url is not matching to your rule

Comment: @mthrsj I have updated question. I have tested that regexp on regexp101.com and it works good. What can be wrong?

Comment: @Chiefir oh, that was horrible mistake `r"^(.*?)(\b{string}\b)(.*)$"` you did not had `format` .... How did I not see that lol... glad you figured it out

Comment: @Umair you did not see that cuz that was not `r`-string, but `f`-string :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, link extractors only search for `a` and `area` tags. The links you are looking for seem to be in `li` tags.

You need to pass the `tags` parameter to the constructor of your link extractor with the desired tags. For example:

```
tags=('a', 'area', 'li')
```

See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml

Comment: super! thanks! p.s. after your code - I had also to fix regexp, like in EDIT 3